# Open the drop-down menu with multiple choices to click

Tags: javascript, html, css

When you click `Press Me`, a drop-down menu opens, and when you click it again or anywhere else in the window, it closes.

I also want to add this function to `dropdown-arrow` next to it, so that it is synchronized.

I tried to give `dropdown-arrow` `onclick="myFunction()"` aswell, but it didn't work.

```js
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-content')[0].classList.toggle('show');
}
// Close dropdown if the user clicks on window
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (!event.target.matches('#verify-name')) {
        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-content');
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
            var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
            if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```css
.buttons {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
}
#dropdown-arrow {
    height: 20px;
}
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
        padding: 14px; background-color: yellow;
}
.show {
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
    <div>
        <a id="verify-name" onclick="myFunction()">Press Me</a>
        <img id="dropdown-arrow" src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/335062/dropdown.svg">

        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <span>Logout</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of 2 ways to tackle your issue:

1. **Attaching a separate click event listener for the dropdown-arrow**.
2. **Using the [*`closest`*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) method to check if the clicked element is `Press Me` text or the `.dropdown-arrow`.**

Let me add the implementation of the second one. First one would be self-explanatory. In below code, I have replaced the `window.onclick` assignment with `window.addEventListener('click', function() {...})` to avoid potential conflicts with other click event listeners and it is also the recommended way.

```js
function toggleDropdown() {
  document.querySelector('.dropdown-content').classList.toggle('show');
}
window.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  const clickedElement = event.target;

  if (clickedElement.closest('#verify-name') || clickedElement.closest('#dropdown-arrow')) {
    // Clicked on "Press Me" or the dropdown-arrow
    toggleDropdown();
  } else {
    // Clicked outside the dropdown elements
    document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-content.show').forEach(function(openDropdown) {
      openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.buttons {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

#dropdown-arrow {
  height: 20px;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 14px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.show {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <div>
    <a id="verify-name">Press Me</a>
    <img id="dropdown-arrow" src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/335062/dropdown.svg">
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <span>Logout</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the onclick event to the dropdown-arrow in your HTML:

```
<img id="dropdown-arrow" src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/335062/dropdown.svg" onclick="myFunction()">
```

Modify the window.onclick function to check for both verify-name and dropdown-arrow:

```
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (!event.target.matches('#verify-name') && !event.target.matches('#dropdown-arrow')) {
        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-content');
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
            var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
            if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
            }
        }
    }
};
```

With these changes, clicking either the "Press Me" link or the dropdown arrow will toggle the dropdown menu. Clicking anywhere else on the window will close it if it's open.